# create a javascript array from a sql query

Tags: php, javascript, sql, amcharts

In fact, my goal is to create a graph with the library amchart
To create the chart, the code is to provide type:

```
var chartData = [{
  date: new Date(2012, 0, 1),
  distance: 227,
  townName: "New York",
  townName2: "New York",
  townSize: 25,
  latitude: 40.71,
  duration: 408
}]
```

I have a sql query that selects me the results to be displayed

```
$test="SELECT dat,SDCCH_Drop, SDCCH_Drop_Rate ,TCH_Assign_unsuccess,
   TCH_Assign_unsuccess_Rate, Call_Setup_Success_Rate
 FROM graph
 WHERE dat BETWEEN '$date_begin' AND '$date_fin' AND nomcel='$cell'";
$te = mysql_query($test)OR DIE("Erreur sur la requeteee");
$gra = array();
$ch1="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($te)) {
  $ch1=$row['dat'];
  $gra[] = $row;
  print_r($row);
} 
$t=json_encode($gra);
```

But I do not see how the results come out in this sql query in an array to davoir:

who can help me please
Thank you!

Comment: iterate through your query result and make array then use `json_encode()`

Comment: I tried but I did not finish

Comment: show us what you tried as code

Comment: i have [{"0":"2012-11-06 00:00:00","dat":"2012-11-06 00:00:00","1":"164","SDCCH_Drop":"164","2":"1.26","SDCCH_Drop_Rate":"1.26","3":"95","TCH_Assign_unsuccess":"95","4":"3.98","TCH_Assign_unsuccess_Rate":"3.98","5":"97.7","Call_Setup_Success_Rate":"97.7"},{"0":"2012-11-07 00:00:00","dat":"2012-11-07

Comment: but I want but I ,"dat":"2012-11-06 00:00:00","SDCCH_Drop":"164","SDCCH_Drop_Rate":"1.26"

Comment: see my answer and change your array style

Comment: return an associative array as a result of the query (mysql_fetch_assoc)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be to run your SQL query, fetch it as an array, and return the results via JSON.  You can call json_ecncode() on the MySQL result array to do this.

You'll need to write both the PHP code to run the query and return the result as well as the javascript to work the JSON response into your chart object.

Comment: can you give me more details please

Comment: i have [{"dat":"2012-11-06 00:00:00","SDCCH_Drop":"164","SDCCH_Drop_Rate":"1.26"}] but the numbers in ""

Answer (score 0):

Change your while and array as below

```
$gra = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($te)) {
 $gra[] = array(
       'dat'=>  $row['dat'],
       'SDCCH_Drop'=>  (int) $row['SDCCH_Drop'],
       'SDCCH_Drop_Rate'=> (float) $row['SDCCH_Drop_Rate']
    );
}
echo json_encode($gra);
```

Comment: i have [{"dat":"2012-11-06 00:00:00","SDCCH_Drop":"164","SDCCH_Drop_Rate":"1.26"}] but the numbers in ""